# Server 2012 R2 First run after sysprep did not prompt for new administrator password

Tags: user-accounts, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, sysprep

I want to know how I can change the User Profile account while the image is restoring when creating a new VM (while setting up the VM).

I had created the image using sysprep and restored it to the new VM in Hyper-V, but it still needed the Administrator authentication to login. But I want to create different user accounts while setting up the VM and log through that account.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to automatically create user accounts during the setup process that runs when first starting a Windows install created from a sysprep image?

Comment: I want to know that too. But now I mainly struggling with creating a account manually(without administrator authentication) like when we installing Windows into a machine.

Comment: So you want to know how to create a user account without using an account that has Administrative rights?

Comment: Yes, I run the sysprep and create the image with administrator Account. I thought administrator Account will be disable or delete from the image. But after I restoring that image it asking the administration password.

Comment: The password is supposed to be blank after running Sysprep (assuming you specified the `/generalize` parameter).  Did you use those parameters?  Did you try nothing for the password?

Comment: Yes I used those parameters. That's why I'm wondering why it's not working.

Comment: Can you logon using the password that was specified before sysprep was run?

Comment: Hang on a sec, you say *after restoring the image it's asking for the administration password*; are you sure it's not asking you to **set** the password for the Administrator account? Because that's what's supposed to happen; after running sysprep it's supposed to ask you what you want the **new** password to be.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Because I did several times but it didn't work. I used Windows server 2012 R2 to create the image.

Comment: Are you using an unattended setup file?

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27499/discussion-between-user3703738-and-twisty).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you got your question resolved in chat, but if you did not, you should know that the Windows Server OOBE process does not prompt for you to create user names, only for an administrator password for the Administrator account. If you want to create new or additional usernames, you’ll need to specify them in your answer file using [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup UserAccounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff716114).